Operator overloading with rust gpu
Is it currecntly possible to do arithmetic operator overloading with rustgpu the way it is done with regular rust?
I tried looking at the crate's documentation but there doesn;t seem to be anything relevant. I know HLSL has operator overloading, so it should be possible at least in theory.
